# Accessing Props from React Ref Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to access props or data-attributes on the ref object of a react component. I have been digging through the component and haven't found anything. Ideally I would like to access the prop valid that I have passed to it. I would be willing to get the data another way but ideally in the ref object if possible.

Comment: post some code showing what you mean and have tried

Comment: I can't show the object exactly. I will see if I can make a working codepen demo

Comment: Does the react ref object give access to props of the component in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React refs are a great way to get a reference to the DOM element rendered by a react component, so you don't actually have access to the component thru refs, just the latest snapshot of what the component printed to the DOM. Have a look at the [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). You do, however, have access to DOM data attributes. Here's an example of how that works. (note: this is not a good way to flow data thru the app)

```
import React from "react";

const CustomDiv = ({ customRef, someProp }) => <div ref={customRef} data-custom-attr={someProp} />;

export default function App() {
    const customRef = React.createRef();

    const clicked = () => {
        console.log(customRef.current);
        console.log(customRef.current.getAttribute("data-custom-attr"));
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <CustomDiv customRef={customRef} someProp={"21"} />
            <button onClick={clicked}>Click Me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the console log after clicking the button will look like:

```
<div data-custom-attr="21"></div>
21
```

You can check out the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-star-eljfk?file=/src/App.js).

Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you can get an attribute just by pulling it off of the `ref`.  Consider the example below.

```js
const {useRef, useEffect} = React;

const Foo = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!ref.current) {
            return;
        }

        console.log(`data-foo is ${ref.current.dataset.foo}`);
    }, []);

    return <div ref={ref} data-foo="foo">I have a data attribute</div>;
};

const App = () => (
    <Foo/>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```